# Find posterior distribution and find marginal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, bayesian, gaussian

We have
z = H s + $\epsilon$
with $\epsilon \sim N(0, R)$ and $s \sim N(\mu, Q)$ where R and Q are symmetric and positive definite. I'm trying to derive the posterior distribution. I have p(s) and p(z|s). However I'm unsure of how to get p(z), and the marginal distribution of y so I can get the posterior distribution p(s|z) using bayes formula. Also R nxn. Q is nxn. H is nxn. s is nx1 and $\epsilon$ is nx1.

p(s) = $\frac{e^{-1/2(s-\mu)^TQ^{-1}(s-\mu)}}{(2*\pi)^{n/2}|Q|^{1/2}} $

p(z|s) = $\frac{e^{-1/2(z-Hs)^TR^{-1}(z-Hs)}}{(2*\pi)^{n/2}|R|^{1/2}} $

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please type out your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of posting it as an image. You would most likely get a more helpful response if you specify what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Thank you just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you find a posterior, it is true that $p(s|z)=\frac{p(z|s)p(s)}{p(z)}$ by Bayes rule. To do this, you would need to calculate the integral $p(z)=\int_{\Omega}p(z|s)p(s)ds$, however this turns out to be a constant (does not depend on s because it has been marginalized out) that will be part of the normalizing factor; consequently, it is more common to use the fact that $p(s|z)\propto p(z|s)p(s)$ to find the posterior density. Here, we can write

$$\begin{split}p(s|z)&\propto p(z|s)p(s)\\
&\propto\exp-\frac 1 2 (s^T-\mu^T)Q^{-1}(s-\mu)\exp-\frac 1 2 (z^T-s^TH^T)R^{-1}(z-Hs)\end{split}$$

Focus on the part inside the exponentiation

$$\begin{split}s^TQ^{-1}s-2\mu^TQ^{-1}s+s^TH^TR^{-1}Hs-2z^TR^THs=\\
s^T\underbrace{(Q^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)}_{=\Sigma^{-1}}s-2\underbrace{(\mu^TQ^{-1}+z^TR^TH)}_{=A^T}s\end{split}$$

We want to write this in the form $(s-m)^T\Sigma^{-1}(s-m)=s^T\Sigma^{-1}s-2m^T\Sigma^{-1}s+m^T\Sigma^{-1}m$
. Let $A^T=m^T\Sigma^{-1}$, then $\Sigma A=m$. So we add and subtract (subtraction is not shown because it is part of the normalizing constant) $A^T\Sigma A$ from the expression.

$$s^T\Sigma^{-1}s-2A^Ts+A^T\Sigma A=(s-\Sigma A)^T\Sigma^{-1}(s-\Sigma A)$$

Thus the posterior of $s$ follows a multivariate normal with mean $\Sigma A=(Q^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1}(Q^{-1}\mu+H^TRz)$ and variance covariance matrix $(Q^{-1}+H^TR^{-1}H)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is super helpful

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how $(−Σ)^Σ^{−1}(−Σ)$ simplifies to p(s|z)

Comment: When simplifying the exponent of p(s|z), let's call that $\theta$ I get, $\theta =z^TR^{-1}z-2s^TH^TR^{-1}z+s^TH^TR^{-1}Hs+s^TQ^{-1}s-2\mu^TQ^{-1}s+\mu^TQ^{-1}\mu$. $\frac{(|)(s)}{p(z)} ∝ \theta$ correct?

Comment: I think it should be $p(s|z)\propto e^{\theta}$, not directly to $\theta$. I left out the $\exp$ when I doing those algebraic manipulations but it should be in an $\exp$. Now that I think about it it wouldn't have been that hard to just write $\exp$ in front.

Comment: Ah I see thank you! I was wrong before when simplifying the exponent of p(s|z), let's call that $\theta$ I get, $\theta =z^TR^{-1}z-2s^TH^TR^{-1}z+s^TH^TR^{-1}Hs+s^TQ^{-1}s-2\mu^TQ^{-1}s+\mu^TQ^{-1}\mu - z^T(R+HQH^T)^{-1}z$. And $\theta$ should simplify to  (s-$\Sigma$A)$^T$$\Sigma^{−1}$(s−$\Sigma$A) right?

Comment: Yes, but where'd you get the last term in the big expression?

Comment: I got it from the marginal density function of z. The marginal density function of z:
$p(z) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}|\Gamma_z|^{1/2}} e^{\frac{-1}{2}z^T\Gamma_z^{-1}z}$
where $\Gamma_z = R + HQH^T$.